# Converting tibble to ts object

Tags: r

I am trying to import data from a csv file, convert it to a tibble then to a ts object.
My issue is that when i plot the ts object, it plots each month as a separate line whereas i would want a single line showing seasonality across years. I cannot provide the data, but i attached the code and plot below:

```
tou<-read_csv("tou_mru.csv")%>%
  rename(month=`Month of arrival`)%>%
  subset(month!="Year",)%>%
  pivot_longer(-month, names_to = "years")%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = month)%>%
  subset(select=January:December)# this provides me with columns for each month 

tou_ts<-ts(data=tou,frequency=1,start=2009)
autoplot(tou_ts)
```

[current plot with multiple lines, i need one with a single one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFQVw.png)

Answer (score 0):

OK so i found the answer, leaving this here in case somebody faces the same situation.
So the ts function only works on numeric vector which meant i had to convert the tibble to numeric vector first then plot.(done below very crudely)

```
    autoplot(ts(as.vector(as.matrix(tou))[13:132],frequency = 12,start=2009))
#we select only 13: 132 because 1:12 is the month header which ts puts naturally
```